# How will find uniq file using md5sum cmmand?

Tags: unix

I am using  Md5sum command ,i get the file content in binary format 
I want the result in without same content available in a file 
for example

```
 $ md5sum file1 file2 file3 file4

  c8675a129a538248bf9b0f8104c8e817  file1
  9d3df2c17bfa06c6558cfc9d2f72aa91  file2
  9d3df2c17bfa06c6558cfc9d2f72aa91  file3
  2e7261df11a2fcefee4674fc500aeb7f  file4
```

I want the output for not matching in a file that mean
file1 and file2 I need .

```
  c8675a129a538248bf9b0f8104c8e817  file1
  2e7261df11a2fcefee4674fc500aeb7f  file4
```

That file content in not same in another file that file only I need

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to solve? Find file duplicates?

Comment: @Jens that file content must contain one file only.

Comment: @etc_passwd I posted an answer on the assumption that you are expecting to find duplicates. If not, post the inputs and the expected output and the logic clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
md5sum file1 file2 file3 file4 | uniq -u -w33
```

in order to get the unique files.

Quoting `man uniq`:

```
   -u, --unique
          only print unique lines
```

---

EDIT: You seem to be looking for alternatives.  Try

```
md5sum ... | sed ':a;$bb;N;/^\(.\).*\n\1[^\n]*$/ba;:b;s/^\(.\).*\n\1[^\n]*\n*//;ta;/./P;D'
```

Comment: Thanks ,any other way

Comment: @etc_passwd So are you looking for alternate approaches that aren't perhaps as simple?

Comment: any other way ,that is simple or complicate.

Comment: @etc_passwd Added an alternative.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this: BASH**

```
find -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 33 | cut -c 35-
```

**Explanation:**

Find all files, calculate their MD5SUM, find duplicates by comparing the MD5SUM, print the names

Read more [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3555/find-duplicate-files-based-on-size-first-then-md5-hash)

Comment: i have used that format ,i want in reverse that is uniq file .